# Dual rail DC-DC converter with higher Vout than specified

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have a TBA 2-0522 from Traco Power supposed to output +/- 12 VDC from +5 VDC as input but instead I'm measuring +/- 19~20 V even under a dummy load. Any idea?

Datasheet: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/687/tba2_datasheet-3049804.pdf

Comment: What dummy load? The datasheet needs 8mA at least to meet specs. Otherwise 20 V sounds like broken, because it's far off.

Comment: It's borked. Did you exceed 220 μF max?  or cause EOS?  https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Electrical_overstress